# How to add custom Types to navigation menu

Tags: plugin-types

I'm using the Types plugin, and I created some custom types, linked to custom fields. It appears in the admin menu, and I can create new entries.

But on the FO, how can I link my Custom type to a menu item ?

When I go to theme->menu, I can select individual entry of my custom Types, but not the custom Types itself, so that its displays a page with the liste of all my entries in it.

I could simulate it with categories, but it should be a more automatic way, no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Post Type Archive Link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-archive-links/) plugin. After enabling it, go to appearence->menu and you will have the option to add the post type archive link on your menu.

Comment: Thank you ! It's strange this feature is not included in wordpress, as it's a very basic feature when dealing with custom types, isn't it ?

Comment: Sure, don't know why they don't include it yet.